# Output as a single list

Tags: python

I created this loop to search for all movies that user watched through user_id. The out put that I want from the statement is just a list statement with genre along the side. Instead, I got a list of the same movie multiple time.

The statement i wrote:

```
title = list(new_merge.loc[new_merge['user_id'] == 55]['title'])
if title != []:
    print('Movie title: ', title, ', Genres: [ ', end = '')
    genres = ast.literal_eval(new_merge.loc[new_merge['user_id'] == 55]['genres'].values[0].split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
    for genre in genres:
        print(genre[:20], ', ', end = '')
    print(']', end = '')
    print('')
```

Screen of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
title = list(set(new_merge.loc[new_merge['user_id'] == 55]['title']))
if len(title) != 0:
    print('Movie title: ', title, ', Genres: [ ', end = '')
    genres = ast.literal_eval(new_merge.loc[new_merge['user_id'] == 55]['genres'].values[0].split('[')[1].split(']')[0])
    for genre in genres:
        print(genre[:20], ', ', end = '')
    print(']', end = '')
    print('')
```

I just used the set in the first line
and I turned it into an array again
I think it will solve your problem

[If you want to know more about "set"](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)

Comment: Pure code answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Please explain the changes you made.

Comment: sorry not good in English

Comment: No problem, try your best. The community can help correct grammar and the sort. Welcome to Stack Overflow.